# Firebase Google SignInWithPopup is blank and error auth/network-request-failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase Google SignInWithPopup in a simple react application. Google sign pop up is blank and errors appears in browser console in few seconds.

The firebase credentials below are modified and won't work for you.

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBhHe4ZQ2e8MFCumIS1bOkLXOACGaU6RF7',
  authDomain: 'my-web.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'my-web',
  storageBucket: 'my-web.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '115533204602',
  appId: '1:115544204602:web:ff796056ae95ae18757fc5',
  measurementId: 'G-LX17LHVKV1',
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

export async function signInWithGoogle() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  window.location.reload();
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on `Sign in with Google` button, I get the popup which is black and gets the error in browser console.

```
code: "auth/network-request-failed"
message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
```

Environment: Chrome
Firebase: ^8.6.0"

I couldn't find a best answer to fix this problem. Can anyone suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: It has started working after 24 hours. I'm afraid that there was  a glitch on firebase auth service.